# Clone an OpenVZ system to run locally

Tags: virtualbox, vmware-player, openvz

I have a VPS on an ISP which is using OpenVZ. I want to run my own image locally to test some services, but I can only download a tar backup of the filesystem.

Can I create a image and run it locally using the tar backup ? I'm on Windows 7. Maybe VMWare Player or Oracle VirtualBox can run this files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. You can install centos 6 and OpenVZ in a virtuall machine and create a container from the backup there. http://openvz.org/Quick_installation